# PHP nested for each/while

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm struggling to understand the syntax of for each/while loops in relation to MySQL queries.

I'm trying to output a list of dates that are grouped by year. I understand that I need a for each loop that contains a while statement...

for each -> 'year' -> list all dates.

I'm not even sure if the 'for each' needs to be a 'for each' (or a 'while').....I'm currently using a 'while' to get the dates list.

This is the code that I'm using to pull out the dates in an un-grouped list that I need to be part of the 'for each'...

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo  [html containing date fields - {$row['year']}{$row['month']}{$row['day']} etc]}
};
```

I'm fairly happy with how to enclose this in an outer loop (year) - I'm just unsure of the syntax to make the outer loop act on the 'year' field.

Comment: this all sounds wrong. Try explainig what you want to acheive. Im sure SQL queries in a loop isnt the answer

Comment: I just need to understand how to group my output by year using the 'year' field from the same query

Comment: Whereever possible, do this type of thing in the database, not php. So you would add GROUP BY to your sql query

Comment: I tried this but could not get an output....I guess I need to simply echo the output instead of trying to loop through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to [IPO principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_Model) you should fetch all your records now and then group them. This keeps your code structured, reusable and easier to read:

```
//fetch all records
$records = array();
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $records[] = $tmp;
}

//group
$finalResult = groupRecordsBy($records, 'month');

function groupRecordsBy($data, $keyToGroupBy) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $index => $record) {
        $result[$record[$keyToGroupBy]][] = $record;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Hope that get's you started!

PS: You should take a look at [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) to even structure your code more! And you should take a look at PHP's **MySQLi** or even better **PDO** instead of using mysql_* functions. They will be marked deprecated soon!

Comment: By default, PHP already throws a notice now when you use mysql in a php script. php.net says: "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future."

Comment: Looks like i've got a lot of reading to do. I'm fine with SQL but know only very little about PHP...maybe I should go on a course!

Answer (score 0):

Check [StackOverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553740/difference-between-foreach-and-while) for the differences between `foreach and while` loop.

For Each Loop Structure as follows-

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo $value ."<br/>";
}
```

And While Loop Structure as follows-

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$i = 0;

while ($i <= count($arr)) {
   $a = $arr[$i];
   echo $a ."<br/>";
   $i++;
}
```